# R date format, how can I change the date format as the 1st June 2011

Tags: r, date, format

I would like to express 2011-06-01 as the format of 2011 June 1st

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is by writing your own routine for suffixing 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th' to what you get from standard functions `strftime()` and/or `format()`.

*Edit:* Here is a rough draft:

```
R> datesuffix <- function(dom) { switch(as.character(dom), 
+                                       "1"="st", "2"="nd", 
+                                        "3"="rd", "th") }
R> nicedate <- function(d) { dlt <- as.POSIXlt(d); 
+                            paste(format(dlt, "%Y %B %e"),
+                                  datesuffix(dlt$mday), sep="") }
R> nicedate(Sys.Date())
[1] "2011 June  9th"
R> nicedate(as.Date("2011-06-01"))
[1] "2011 June  1st"
```

*Edit 2* I guess you wanted the date string reordered. I've been in North America for too long...

```
R> nicedate <- function(d) { dlt <- as.POSIXlt(d); 
+                            paste(as.character(dlt$mday), 
+                                  datesuffix(dlt$mday),
+                                  format(dlt, " %B %Y"), sep="") }
R> nicedate(as.Date("2011-06-01"))
[1] "1st June 2011"
R> nicedate(as.Date("2011-06-02"))
[1] "2nd June 2011"
R> nicedate(Sys.Date())
[1] "9th June 2011"
R>
```

*Edit 3* Had to correct `datesuffix()` to convert to char first.

Comment: can you specify the script? I am confused about all the time conversion thx!

Comment: Eva, as Joris astutely observes, the only real remedy is to ... study the help files and other documentation.

Comment: @Eva, if you read the help file of `?strftime`, the first example may be what you're looking for (but it would pay off if you read the whole darn thing :) ).

Comment: For extra credit come up with a multilingual solution (e.g 2eme Juin 2011 ...)

Comment: Nice idea, but I will leave that for the esteemed professor to complete. Here in Illinois we have only one official language :)

Comment: Changing the month to another language would be easy if you change it session wide with `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", Spanish_Argentina.1252)` for example. And changing the endiding could be done with an extra switch looking up at the time locale.